# I can't use transparent background with imagecopymerge

Tags: php, image-manipulation, gd

I am calling `imagecopymerge($dst_r, $logo, 0, 0, 0, 0, $LogoX, $LogoY, 100);` where `$logo` is a png file with transparent background. From some reason the background comes out white instead.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [`imagealphablending($dst_r, TRUE);`](http://php.net/imagealphablending) to allow copying with retaining the transparent colors. Many [more comments (...)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) in the manual suggest using `imagecopy` instead, because imagecopymerge was never intended to be used with transparency. If you use `pct=100` anyway, then the normal imagecopy might be an option.

Comment: Here is a [concrete example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php#85754)  make sure to call `imagealphablending` and `imagesavealpha` after you create your png image

Comment: using imagecopy instead of imagecopymerge saved my day

Answer (score -1):

This is for text, but you can get the point. It would be more helpful if you post entire code.

```
$font = 25;
$string = "Hello";
$im = @imagecreatetruecolor(strlen($string) * $font / 1.5, $font);
imagesavealpha($im, true);
imagealphablending($im, false);
$white = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $white);
$lime = imagecolorallocate($im, 204, 255, 51);
imagettftext($im, $font, 0, 0, $font - 3, $lime, "font.ttf", $string);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```