# Change the opacity of an image in PHP

Tags: php, image, gd, opacity, transparent

I am trying to change the opacity of an image using GD, Almost all the solutions that I found are similar to the code below, where you create a white transparent background and merge it with your image.

But this doesn't make the image transparent, the image just gets brighter, you can't actually look through it.

So my question is, how to change the opacity of an image so that you can look through it?
Or am i doing something wrong with this code?

```
//Create an image with a white transparent background color
$newImage = ImageCreateTruecolor(300, 300);
$bg        = ImageColorAllocateAlpha($newImage, 255, 255, 255, 127);
ImageFill($newImage, 0, 0, $bg);

//Get the image
$source = imagecreatefrompng('my_image.png');

$opacity = 50;    

//Merge the image with the background
ImageCopyMerge($newImage,
               $source,
               0, 0, 0, 0,
               300,
               300,
               $opacity);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($newImage);
imagedestroy($newImage);
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure, but is this just a matter of not calling `imagealphablending` (or `imagesavealpha`)?

Comment: After a quick search, possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529306/i-cant-use-transparent-background-with-imagecopymerge

Comment: Have you tried changing the opacity with CSS?

Comment: @abarnert Yes I think that could have something to do with it, I tried messing with those functions but no luck so far. I will take a look at the other question.

Comment: @JohnDoe Changing the opacity with CSS is not what I am trying to do, I am trying to Change it with PHP so I can save the image again.

Comment: @RobertHegeraad changing the opacity with css still might work, are you planning on exporting it? Or are you just wanting to leave it on your site.

Answer (score 17):

You just need to use `imagefilter` with `IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE`

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng('my_image.png');
$opacity = 0.5;
imagealphablending($image, false); // imagesavealpha can only be used by doing this for some reason
imagesavealpha($image, true); // this one helps you keep the alpha. 
$transparency = 1 - $opacity;
imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 0,0,0,127*$transparency); // the fourth parameter is alpha
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
```

`imagealphablending`, I think, is for drawing purposes so you don't want to use it. I may be wrong. We should both look it up :)

If you want to use percentage, you can calculate `$opacity` accordingly.

Comment: Experiments show that neither `imagealphablending` nor `imagesavealpha` values affect the `imagefilter` result both for transparent and opaque images. Perhaps they affect the `imagepng` result.

Answer (score 7):

There is no direct way to change opacity using DG function (actually [there is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41406201/1118709)). But it can be done using pixel-by-pixel manipulation:

```
/**
 * @param resource $imageSrc Image resource. Not being modified.
 * @param float $opacity Opacity to set from 0 (fully transparent) to 1 (no change)
 * @return resource Transparent image resource
 */
function imagesetopacity( $imageSrc, $opacity )
{
    $width  = imagesx( $imageSrc );
    $height = imagesy( $imageSrc );

    // Duplicate image and convert to TrueColor
    $imageDst = imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );
    imagealphablending( $imageDst, false );
    imagefill( $imageDst, 0, 0, imagecolortransparent( $imageDst ));
    imagecopy( $imageDst, $imageSrc, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height );

    // Set new opacity to each pixel
    for ( $x = 0; $x < $width; ++$x )
        for ( $y = 0; $y < $height; ++$y ) {
            $pixelColor = imagecolorat( $imageDst, $x, $y );
            $pixelOpacity = 127 - (( $pixelColor >> 24 ) & 0xFF );
            if ( $pixelOpacity > 0 ) {
                $pixelOpacity = $pixelOpacity * $opacity;
                $pixelColor = ( $pixelColor & 0xFFFFFF ) | ( (int)round( 127 - $pixelOpacity ) << 24 );
                imagesetpixel( $imageDst, $x, $y, $pixelColor );
            }
        }

    return $imageDst;
}

$source = imagecreatefrompng( 'my_image.png' );
$newImage = imagesetopacity( $source, 0.5 );
imagedestroy( $source );

header( 'Content-Type: image/png' );
imagepng( $newImage );
imagedestroy( $newImage );
```

Comment: acutally there is. check out my answer

Comment: if you have round image then it convert into square in new image. so its not working properly.

Comment: @AjayBhayani, what do yo mean saying "round image"? If you mean an image with transparent corners, you make a mistake somewhere because this code regards the original image transparency.

Comment: Best solution via gdlib, thx!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting alpha blending to true?

`imagealphablending($newImage,true);`