# PHP GD images not merging

Tags: php, merge, gd

I'm currently creating a an image from a base64 png, then merging another png over it. My code looks as follows, but temp.png is just empty, even though $fileName's output is still the original image.:

```
session_start();

$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$img = $_POST['img'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$fileData = base64_decode($img);
$fileName = "./gallery/" . bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16)) . ".png";
file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData);

//Merge Two Images
header ("Content-type: image/png");
$background = imagecreatefrompng($fileName);
$pkt = imagecreatefrompng("./frames/frame1.png");
$insert_x = imagesx($pkt);
$insert_y = imagesy($pkt);
imagecopymerge($background,$pkt,0,0,0,0,$insert_x,$insert_y,100);
imagepng($background,"temp.png",100);
```

Comment: Maybe something about your png transparancy. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529306/i-cant-use-transparent-background-with-imagecopymerge)

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying a `copyMerge()` with a percentage of 100; that's not really a *merge*, if the image sizes are equal, it's just copying. You should see only the image in `frame1`.

If you are relying on the alpha channel, verify using e.g the `pnginfo` utility that both images have valid alpha components.

Comment: It's completely empty though, not even the first image. I've tried using prebuilt images too, and both exist when I hover over the links in the editor, but it's still empty.

Comment: Can you put the images somewhere? I can try out your code later today.

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help. Just figured it out and wrote it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Iserni for pointing out that it's not a merge. I wrote a little function as follows:

```
function imagecopymerge_alpha($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h, $pct)
{
    $cut = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w, $src_h); 

    imagecopy($cut, $dst_im, 0, 0, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_w, $src_h);
    imagecopy($cut, $src_im, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h);
    imagecopymerge($dst_im, $cut, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $src_w, $src_h, $pct); 
}
```

Hope this helps someone!